# Split date periods by months and add rows in case of necessity

Tags: r, date

I have a table:

```
Name| Start     | Finish    |
----|-----------|-----------|
A   |2015-01-22 |2015-02-04 |
B   |2015-01-02 |2015-01-10 |
A   |2015-01-22 |2015-02-14 |
B   |2015-01-02 |2015-02-10 |
```

I need to break periods by months. If a period starts in one month and ends in the next one then I need to split it into two periods. If a period starts and ends at the same month then it should be as it is. Let's assume period cannot contain more than one 1st day of the month. In other words, each line can be splitted for not more than two lines. Finish (end of the period) is always bigger than Start.

That's what I want to get:

```
Name| Start     | Finish    |
----|-----------|-----------|
A   |2015-01-22 |2015-01-31 |
A   |2015-02-01 |2015-02-04 |
A   |2015-01-22 |2015-01-31 |
A   |2015-02-01 |2015-02-14 |
B   |2015-01-02 |2015-01-10 |
B   |2015-01-02 |2015-01-31 |
B   |2015-02-01 |2015-02-10 |
```

The order of output rows isn't a matter.

Here is a code for the table:

```
Name = c("A", "B", "A", "B")
Start = c(as.Date("2015-01-22"), as.Date("2015-01-02"), as.Date("2015-01-22"), as.Date("2015-01-02"))
Finish = c(as.Date("2015-02-04"), as.Date("2015-01-10"), as.Date("2015-02-14"), as.Date("2015-02-10"))
df = data.frame(Name, Start, Finish)
```

Any suggestion how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been changed. Originally the `Name` column uniquely identified the row but the changed version of the question no longer has that. The answer here has been modified accordingly so that now we identify rows by row number, i.e. `1:nrow(df)`, rather than `df$Name` in the second argument to `by`.   Otherwise, code is unchanged.

Use `by` to split the data frame by row giving single rows and operating on each one with the anonymous function.  It calculates the end-of-month (`eom`) for the Start and if the Finish is greater outputs a two-row data frame and otherwise returns the same data frame.  Put it all together with `rbind`.

```
library(zoo)

do.call("rbind", by(df, 1:nrow(df), function(x) with(x, {
   eom <- as.Date(as.yearmon(Start), frac = 1)
   if (eom < Finish)
      data.frame(Name, Start = c(Start, eom+1), Finish = c(eom, Finish))
   else x
})))
```

giving:

```
    Name      Start     Finish
1.1    A 2015-01-22 2015-01-31
1.2    A 2015-02-01 2015-02-04
2      B 2015-01-02 2015-01-10
3.1    A 2015-01-22 2015-01-31
3.2    A 2015-02-01 2015-02-14
4.1    B 2015-01-02 2015-01-31
4.2    B 2015-02-01 2015-02-10
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly on the initial two-rows df provided. However, on the bigger datasets generate wrong output. Cannot find out why. I have made an edit of the question and have added a couple of rows to the initial data frame.

Comment: In the original question Name uniquely identified the rows but in the changed one it does not.  I have changed the answer accordingly to address this change.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

This answers the original question:

```
require(dplyr)
require(zoo)

df %>%
  filter(Finish>as.Date(as.yearmon(Start),frac=1)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  do(rbind(.,c(.$Name,
               paste(as.Date(as.yearmon(.$Start),frac=1)+1),
               .$Finish))) %>%
  mutate(Finish:=ifelse(as.Date(as.yearmon(Start),frac=1)<Finish,
                        paste(as.Date(as.yearmon(Start),frac=1)),Finish))
```

Output:

```
   Name      Start     Finish
1     A 2015-01-22 2015-01-31
2     A 2015-02-01 2015-02-04
3     B 2015-03-02 2015-03-31
4     B 2015-04-01 2015-04-10
```

Sample data:

```
require(data.table)
df <- fread("Name Start      Finish    
             A    2015-01-22 2015-02-01 
             B    2015-03-02 2015-04-01")
```

Comment: The output you provided is not exactly the same as the target one. And I have just added rows to the initial table to test on a bigger set.

Comment: @Sergiy - That's because I added data to improve error testing. This is still a solution to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach in base R:

```
idx <- with(df, format(Finish, "%Y-%m") > format(Start, "%Y-%m"))

rbind(df[!idx,],
   transform(df[idx,], Finish = as.Date(paste0(format(Finish, "%Y-%m"), "-01"))-1),
   transform(df[idx,], Start  = as.Date(paste0(format(Finish, "%Y-%m"), "-01"))))

#   Name      Start     Finish
#2     B 2015-01-02 2015-01-10
#1     A 2015-01-22 2015-01-31
#3     A 2015-01-22 2015-01-31
#4     B 2015-01-02 2015-01-31
#11    A 2015-02-01 2015-02-04
#31    A 2015-02-01 2015-02-14
#41    B 2015-02-01 2015-02-10
```

Comment: Perfect solution within the base R. But I just accepted the previous answer.